# iPhone SDK : Is it possible to record the you talking time?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

First ,this is my friends idea ,girls always use cell phone talk too much

every month they receive the billing will cost them a lot of money

they ask me is there any applications to calculate how long they dial out a month

or maybe can pop up a alert to notice them time is up,please hang up the phone

maybe 3 mins or 5 mins (some telecommunications provider offer free talk at first 3 mins )

So.......is it possible to use application to record your talking time and give you a notice ?

I'm just a new iphone programmer ,I have no idea about this ~

Even if this is impossible , still can share some information to me

It's help me to answer my friend

thanks :)

Comment: No need to write a program to do this. Pretty much every wireless company's website can provide users with usage data for (at least) the current month.

Comment: I will go to check.But it still better can write on a SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Using the wireless company's website would be the simplest way.  If you really wanted a native iPhone app that would track time you could probably write one that utilized iOS's new multitasking abilities.

Essentially, the 10,000 foot view of the app would be something that a user would launch before making a phone call.  When launched, they could start a timer (or delayed timer), move the app to the background (by tapping on the home button on a iDevice that supports background apps).  The app's timer would continue to run in the background while the user makes their phone call.

I believe phone calls can be moved to the background as well, so users could go back to the app and check how much time they've been on the phone call.

Complicated, but doesn't require jail breaking.  The implementation could be improved a ton, but that's the 1 minute, proof of concept, that you seemed to be looking for.

Comment: OK...so maybe I can write a app to connect to the wireless company website ,and refresh data every few seconds ,and make notice by code?

Comment: yes, you could make a screen scraper that would pull info from the carrier site.  At the very least you'd need the user to provide their login credentials.

Comment: Bear in mind, that this kind of thing has been done successfully by MANY other apps, so you are kind of reinventing the wheel if you are hoping to make money off it.

Comment: I don't think this app can make any money...I don't even have an iphone